# HTML Landing page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a landing page where it shows 2 logos. On hover a background image should appear on the left hand side of the page but should fill from top to bottom. At the moment it's only filling the div container of the logo. I'm not that good at coding and got help with creating these codes.

Code Below

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
}

.left-logo,
.right-logo {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.left-logo img,
.right-logo img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

.left-bg,
.right-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.left-logo:hover .left-bg {
  opacity: 1;
  background-image: url(images/bg-left.png);
}

.right-logo:hover .right-bg {
  opacity: 1;
  background-image: url(images/bg-right.png);
}

.left-logo img,
.right-logo img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left-logo">
        <img src="images/logo-left.png" alt="Left Logo">
        <div class="left-bg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-logo">
        <img src="images/logo-right.png" alt="Right Logo">
        <div class="right-bg"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Tried to put the image in the css code where left-bg is but still didn't work.

Comment: _"Tried to put it in the background but didn't work"_ - no idea what that is supposed to actually mean. Please show us what you actually tried, in code, instead of giving vague verbal descriptions that could mean any number of possible things.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding height: 100vh; and width: 100%; to the .row class and margin:0; to the body tag as follows:

```css
body {
background-color: white;
margin: 0;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100vh;
}

.row {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}

.left-logo, .right-logo {
width: 50%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
}

.left-logo img, .right-logo img {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 5s;
}

.left-bg, .right-bg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.left-logo:hover .left-bg {
opacity: 1;
background-image: url(https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/sa_pixar_virtualbg_coco_16x9_9ccd7110.jpeg);
}

.right-logo:hover .right-bg {
opacity: 1;
background-image: url(https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/sa_pixar_virtualbg_coco_16x9_9ccd7110.jpeg);
}

.left-logo img, .right-logo img {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left-logo">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSOyCtPSy5vZ6NNKe6nmW5aEAWDfv2R3bV72g&usqp=CAU" alt="Left Logo">
        <div class="left-bg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-logo">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSOyCtPSy5vZ6NNKe6nmW5aEAWDfv2R3bV72g&usqp=CAU" alt="Right Logo">
        <div class="right-bg"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean the left and right?

Comment: Hi I've increase the width from 80% to 100% and it worked

Comment: If I would need to make the background a clickable link where should the href be? Before the div class left-bg?

Comment: yes, make sure to close the tag after the respective div

Comment: Hi @AndreaCamilleri, I hope I could help you. Let me know if you need any changes.